# codeigniter post_system hook calls before rendering page

Tags: php, codeigniter

By default Codeigniter's `post_system` hook should be called after the final rendered page is sent to the browser. But it is calling before rendering page.

I have a `curl` function in this hook. So if internet is slow, the time taking to load the page increases.

I want to call this hook function only after final page rendered.

Is this a Codeigniter bug?

Comment: I'd suggest an `ajax` call instead of that hook. Easy *and* async

Comment: You just created a dependency in your entire application. Why would you want to do that? @AlexTartan 's suggestion isn't half-bad.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is to another domain. Browser will not support cross domain Ajax calling.

Comment: Create a single ajax action in a controller that will do that for you. You do NOT want a dependency like that. Plus you have the added advantage of sanitizing whatever the other server throws at you. E.g., if the people of the other server decide to map the output differently, you can still maintain yours in your front-end. Or if it be down, your visitors will not (or hardly) experience 'lag' nor the consequence of it not responding.

Comment: Ok thanks, Let me do do like that.